# Cannot convert <function array_str at 0x02F1E978> to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, numpy

I keep getting the error above even though I tried to convert everything to object or string.

```
df['temp'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
nd = df['Date'].unique() nd = np.array_str
```

I want to get the unique value in column Date of df to be the column header. I want this value to show as MM/DD/YYYY. The result in Python appears as "0x02F1E978". It should have been 09/25/2017 and I can write the file to Excel at all.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, datetime


path = 'C:/Users/tnguy075/Desktop/Inventory Valuation/'

file1 = 'AH_INDY_COMBINEDINV_VALUE_TIDL.xlsx'
file2 = 'DailyInventoryVal.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path+file1, skiprows=1, dtype={'Valuation': np.float64}, parse_dates=['Date']) #open the daily data

df['temp'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))#change it to a string in form of MM/DD/YYYY
nd = df['Date'].unique()
nd = np.array_str

df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Key"], values=["Valuation"],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()

df.columns = ['Key',nd]

dv = pd.read_excel(path+file2) 
dv = dv.merge(df[['Key', nd]], how = 'left')#Merge data from file 1 using Key

dv.to_excel('path+DaivalReport.xlsx')
```

Comment: missing `()` in `nd = np.array_str()`

Comment: Such a silly mistake! Thanks, Jezrael!

Comment: now it says, array_str() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a' and I havent been able to found the answer for this error. Do you happen to know

Comment: I think `nd = np.array_str(nd)`, check [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html)

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks for your help and patience! I'm a first time coder :)

Comment: We don't use [solved] title devices here - would you add the answer below? Thanks!